# JInternalFrame to front and focussed

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

How does one push a `JInternalFrame` to the top of all the frames in a JDesktopPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the JInternalFrame API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Internal Frames" where you will find a working example of how to "select" the active internal frame.

Comment: DestopManager.activateFrame(frame) turned out to be the solution. I derived it from one of the examples in there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dah, I would have thought frame.setSelected(true) would be easier. This is what the example uses every time a new frame is created. I've never seen the activateFrame() method referenced in the tutorials.

Comment: I have an app where setSelected also doesn't work on Ubuntu, but it works on Windows and Mac.

Comment: @Chinasaur: I'm using Ubuntu and setSelected() seems to works fine.

Answer (score 3):

try     grabFocus()  and requestFocus(). One of the should work. I personally used only requestFocus().

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also (if it did work), according to the API, you should be using requestFocusInWindow().

Comment: Didn't work. Ended up using desktop.getDesktopManager().activateFrame(jif); where JIF is a JInternalFrame

Comment: neither grabFocus(), requestFocus() or transferFocus() works in this case. setSelected(true), worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/2e1b14bcad9bd7fa), a `javax.swing.Action` is used to select frames from a menu.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has noted that `setSelected` was not working, and he needed to call `activateFrame` manually.  This sounds similar to an issue I was having with `GTKLookAndFeel`.  I had an application that was all wired up to use `setSelected` to eventually trigger `activateFrame`.  Worked fine with Windows and Mac native look and feel; `activateFrame` would get called automatically.

On Ubuntu, the system selected LaF was `GTKLookAndFeel` and for whatever reason this was not calling `activateFrame`.  It didn't appear that `setSelected` was throwing an error or anything, it just wasn't getting around to calling `activateFrame` as the other LaFs seem to do.  I think it's a `GTKLookAndFeel` compatibility issue.

In the end I punted on this and just prohibited `GTKLookAndFeel`, replacing it with `Metal`.  `Motif` also had the compatible behavior (but it's so ugly...).  The code looks something like this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
if (UIManager.getLookAndFeel() instanceof com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel)
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: +1 Probably that's explains it. I'm using "Nimbus" in Ubuntu, and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

/*make current JInternalFrame deselected by calling JInternalFrame method setSelected(false)

*/then select new JInternalFrame using the same method; ie setSelected(true)

sample code:

try{
 jframe1.setSelected(false);
 jframe2.setSelected(true);
}catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {}

Answer (score 1):

[Closing a modal JInternalFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827847/closing-a-modal-jinternalframe/5454351#5454351)
see the post by Mr. Zen(me)