# about Java Swing inner window(?)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make something with Java Swing. 
now I am using JInternalFrame but because it looks separated window, I would like to know if I can create some inner panels(?) like this picture using Java swing.
I want to create each one whenever a button is clicked. 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I do not know if you want to make tabs or dockable frames. But for tabs you can use JTabbedPane and for docks you can use one of java swing docking frameworks like

Comment: If you don't want resize the components, you could use a GridLayout

Comment: @docDevil could you let me know how to use java swing docking frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Although `JInternalFrame` is intended for use in a `JDesktopPane`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), you might try them in a `JPanel` having a narrow-gap `GridLayout(1, 0, 2, 2)`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392620/230513).

[image]