# Does javafx support MDI (Multiple document interface)?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am designing program and I need to use MDI (Multiple document interface) and I don't know how to do so so please could anyone answer me.
There is video on YouTube doing MDI in javafx but there is no source code or explanation of the video the video link is :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nskbRY-Tnw .
Please help me with this it is shame to javafx to not allow us to manage windows inside other windows.

Comment: There is no abstraction for child windows baked into Java FX2 or, as far as I know, FX8.

Answer (score 5):

MDI is largely considered to be a [poor user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi) and, partly as a consequence of that, there is no built-in MDI API in the current version of JavaFX.

However, if you really wanted to implement an application like that, it wouldn't be too difficult. Use a plain `Pane` to hold the individual windows, and implement the windows using `BorderPane`s, with the top region holding a title bar and some buttons. You'd need to do a bit of work to implement the mouse listeners for dragging and focus, but not too much.

Comment: +1 for saying "please don't". :-) May I suggest using either free floating windows or probably better, a single window, full size tabbed pane.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a MDI interface in 10 minutes, using JavaFX for the core and Swing for the Internal Frames. If you want to go this way you have to deal with:

- JInternalFrame [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817190/about-java-swing-inner-window), [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) and [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)
- [JavaFX-Swing Interoperability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm#JFXIP561)

Answer (score 0):

JVx by SIB Visions seems to work on some MDI support for JavaFX: http://blog.sibvisions.com/2015/03/19/javafx-styled-stage-and-mdi-system/

That said, please note that I'm currently working on a [Docking Framework for JavaFX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DockingFramework), which might interest you as an alternative to a MDI approach.

The annotations are currently only available inside [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX) applications, but the programmatic approach is also available for non-OSGi environments (see the [sample](http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-commons/ci/drombler-commons-0.6/tree/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-docking/)).

Please note that there is a [Getting Started](http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted) page for Drombler FX based applications, which support the Docking Framework annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard to accomplish with JavaFX - but I agree it's too bad it's not native.  While I am not crazy about the idea, some use cases exist for it.

Have you main window use a Pane as the location where the windows will open in.  Then you can use a CustomPane which holds a scrollpane in it.  Then you can load your FXML into this object...

```
public class MoveablePane extends Pane {
    private ScrollPane scrollArea;
    private Node  contentNode;
    public MoveablePane (String title, Node contentNode) {

    this.contentNode = contentNode;

    //Set up the title bar
    //Set up the window buttons
    //Place the node into the scroll area so the user can resize
    this.scrollArea = new ScrollPane(contentNode);
    //Add the nodes to be layed out on the stage
    this.getChildren().clear();
    this.getChildren().addAll(scrollArea);
}
```

....

Then you need to implement the drag & resize events & layout children...

For example:

```
private void dragPaneToNewLocation(MouseEvent event) {

    // Get the exact moved X and Y
    double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - mousex;
    double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - mousey;

    x += offsetX;
    y += offsetY;

    double scaledX = x;
    double scaledY = y;

    if(scaledY > 0){
        setLayoutY(scaledY);
    }

    if(scaledX > 0){
        setLayoutX(scaledX);
    }


    // again set current Mouse x AND y position
    mousex = event.getSceneX();
    mousey = event.getSceneY();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i found a way to do MDI APP just by using the jfxtra library

Comment: How did you manage this?

Comment: @Troyseph I've not tried it (It's on the TODO list), but I think Hassan is referring to the jfxtras.scene.control.window.Window class. See https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/9.0/jfxtras-window/src/main/java/jfxtras/scene/control/window/Window.java "Window control. A window control is a window node as known from Swing. It can be used to realize MDI based applications. See https://github.com/miho/VFXWindows-Samples for sample code."