# Keep focus of JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, focus, jinternalframe

Is there any way to keeps focus of a JInternalFrame, I mean, always focused until it closed or showVisible(false) etc? I already search for a while but I only found a "temporary" focus, that is when you click another JInternalFrame (for example) the focus switched. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a JInternalFrame for this. Use a modal JDialog.

Answer (score 1):

[Closing a modal JInternalFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827847/closing-a-modal-jinternalframe/5454351#5454351)
See the one by me (Mr. Zen)